# Webpack@5.66.0 Webpack dev server config: options has an unknown property 'stats'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Invalid options object. Dev server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- optionshas an unknown property 'stats'. These properties are valid:
  object { allowedHost?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

webpack.dev.server.js

````
module.exports = function getDevServerConfig(options) {
...
...
const devServer = {
...
...
disableHostCheck: true,
noInfo: false,
stats: {
assets: true,
color: true
}

}

}```
````

Comment: Dev server has been initialized using an options object that does not match API schema.
- options has an unknown property 'stats'. 
- options has an unknown property 'info'. 
- options has an unknown property 'disableHostCheck'. 
These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHost?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Comment: Any luck with this error? I have this same issue today ill be trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

From the `webpack-dev-server` v4 migration guide:

> `fs`, `index`, `mimeTypes`, `publicPath`, `serverSideRender`, `stats`, and
> `writeToDisk` (related to `webpack-dev-middleware`) were moved to
> `devMiddleware` option.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting node_modules and yarn.lock. After that I ran yarn to rebuild node_modules and then yarn start worked without an issue.